# Access std::deque from 3 threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have a buffer of type std::deque. 
There is a thread to write into it, another one to read from it,  and the last one to handle some conditions for which item in the buffer to forward.

I just want to access this buffer safely from the 3 threads. Yup,  I'm very beginner :-)

I created a mutex and every time I access the buffer I wrap this access by

```
myMutex. lock() ;
// access here
myMutex. unlock() ;
```

Also, I used std::thread myThread(this, &fn) to create the threads. And I call this_thread::sleep() frequently to reduce cpu load

My problem is I got Exeption says abort() has been called! When I debug it fails when I call myThread.join() 
What is the fault!!

**EDIT: code added**
this is my main sending function

```
void UDPStreamSender::SendStream(const char* sendMsg, size_t size)
{

    cout << "---- Send Stream starts... ----" << endl;

    char* longMsg = new char[size];
    memcpy(longMsg, sendMsg, size);

    std::thread segThread(&UDPStreamSender::DoSegmentation, this, longMsg, size);
    _isRunning = true;
    std::thread sendThrad(&UDPStreamSender::SendBuffer, this);
    std::thread ackThrad(&UDPStreamSender::AckRecive, this);
    std::thread timeOutThread(&UDPStreamSender::ManageTimeout, this);


    sendThrad.join();
    ackThrad.join();
    timeOutThread.join();

    cout << "---- Send Stream done! ----" << endl;
}
```

fn's on the worker threads

```
void UDPStreamSender::DoSegmentation(const char* longMsg, unsigned int size)
{
    Segment* cSeg = new Segment();
    cSeg->seqNum = lastSeqNum;

    msgLength = size;
    msgSegLen = segLength - SEQ_NUM_LEN;

    segmentsNumber = (unsigned int)ceil((float)msgLength / (msgSegLen));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < segmentsNumber; i++)
    {

        cSeg->seqNum++;
        lastSeqNum = cSeg->seqNum;

        cSeg->data = new char[msgSegLen];

        int sendMsgSegLen = msgSegLen;
        if (i == segmentsNumber - 1)
            sendMsgSegLen = msgLength - i*msgSegLen;

        memcpy(cSeg->data, longMsg + i*msgSegLen, sendMsgSegLen);

        // Add to send buffer
        while (sendBuffer->isFull())
        {
            this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
        }
        cSeg->isSent = false;

        bufLock.lock();
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(bufLock);
        sendBuffer->Add(cSeg);
        bufLock.unlock();
    }
    cv.notify_all();
}

void UDPStreamSender::SendBuffer()
{
    bufLock.lock();
    bool hasElms = sendBuffer->hasElems();
    bufLock.unlock();

    while (_isRunning || hasElms)
    {
        bufLock.lock();
        size_t firstUnsent = sendBuffer->firstUnsent();
        size_t buffCount = sendBuffer->count();
        bufLock.unlock();

        if (firstUnsent == buffCount)
        {
            this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
            continue;
        }
        for (size_t i = firstUnsent; i < buffCount; i++)
        {
            bufLock.lock();
            Segment sSeg = sendBuffer->at(i);
            int st = SendSegment(&sSeg);
            if (st >= segLength)
            {
                sSeg.isSent = true;
                DWORD j = GetTickCount();
                sSeg.timeOutTick = j + timeOutTicks;
                sendBuffer->Replace(i, &sSeg);
                sendBuffer->sendSeg();
                cout << "SEG sent: SeqNum=" << sSeg.seqNum << endl;
            }
            bufLock.unlock();
        }
        bufLock.lock();
        hasElms = sendBuffer->hasElems();
        bufLock.unlock();
    }
}

void UDPStreamSender::AckRecive()
{
    char* ackMessage;
    while (!_allRecived)
    {
        ackMessage = ackReciver->Recive();

        string ackMsg(ackMessage);
        if (ackMsg.substr(0, 3).compare("ACK") != 0)
            continue;

        unsigned short ackSeqNum = 0;
        memcpy(&ackSeqNum, ackMessage + 3, 2);

        cout << "ACK recieved: seqNum=" << ackSeqNum << endl;

        bufLock.lock();
        sendBuffer->Ack(ackSeqNum);
        _allRecived = !sendBuffer->hasElems();
        bufLock.unlock();
    }
}

void UDPStreamSender::ManageTimeout()
{
    bufLock.lock();
    bool hasElms = sendBuffer->hasElems();
    bufLock.unlock();

    while (hasElms)
    {
        bufLock.lock();

        DWORD segTick = sendBuffer->first().timeOutTick;
        DWORD cTick = GetTickCount();
        if (sendBuffer->hasElems() && cTick > segTick)
        { // timeout, resend all buffer
            sendBuffer->resendAll();
            cout << "Timeout: seqNum=" << sendBuffer->first().seqNum << endl;
        }
        bufLock.unlock();
        this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));

        bufLock.lock();
        hasElms = sendBuffer->hasElems();
        bufLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

I know that is a lot of threads there, but it's just an assignment !

Comment: Where's the code? Your snippet of lock/unlock tells nothing of what might actually be causing the problem

Comment: Have you tried compiling with `-pthread`?

Comment: @KerrekSB I really don't know what is "-pthread"!

Comment: `-pthread` is a compiler option. Just like you would add `-std=gnu++11` for compiling c++11 code in a compiler that doesn't support that, `-pthread` is for compiling posix thread code.

Comment: What compiler are you using, ie GCC, VisualStudio, Clang? What is the exact error message? Check the size in memcpy in DoSegmentation, you may be overwritten memory. Better don't use new[], use std::vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried and tried!
the error come form the way I lock() and unlock() the mutex.

That is insted `bufLock.lock()`, use `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mtx_lock(bufLock);` to lock the deque buffer.

Also Two variable_condition is needed to handle the cases of isEmpty and isFull to stop forwarding, adding to the buffer.

The final code if anyone finds it useful.

**NOTE:** this code eats a lot memory and consume the CPU, don't use it without revision. And WELCOME to help me with it :)

```
void UDPStreamSender::SendStream(const char* sendMsg, size_t size)
{
    InitializeNewSendSession();
    cout << "---- Send Stream starts... ----" << endl;

    char* longMsg = new char[size];
    memcpy(longMsg, sendMsg, size);

    std::thread segThread(&UDPStreamSender::DoSegmentation, this, longMsg, size);
    _isRunning = true;
    std::thread sendThrad(&UDPStreamSender::SendBuffer, this);
    std::thread ackThrad(&UDPStreamSender::AckRecive, this);
    std::thread timeOutThread(&UDPStreamSender::ManageTimeout, this);

    segThread.join();
    sendThrad.join();
    _isRunning = false;
    ackThrad.join();
    timeOutThread.join();

    cout << "---- Send Stream done! ----" << endl;
}

void UDPStreamSender::DoSegmentation(const char* longMsg, unsigned int size)
{
    Segment* cSeg = new Segment();
    cSeg->seqNum = lastSeqNum;

    msgLength = size;
    msgSegLen = segLength - SEQ_NUM_LEN;

    segmentsNumber = (unsigned int)ceil((float)msgLength / (msgSegLen));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < segmentsNumber; i++)
    {

        cSeg->seqNum++;
        lastSeqNum = cSeg->seqNum;

        cSeg->data = new char[msgSegLen];

        int sendMsgSegLen = msgSegLen;
        if (i == segmentsNumber - 1)
            sendMsgSegLen = msgLength - i*msgSegLen;

        memcpy(cSeg->data, longMsg + i*msgSegLen, sendMsgSegLen);

        // Add to send buffer
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mtx_lock(bufLock);
        while (sendBuffer->isFull())
        {
            stopifFull.wait(mtx_lock);
        }
        cSeg->isSent = false;

        sendBuffer->Add(cSeg);
        mtx_lock.unlock();
        stopIfEmpty.notify_all();
    }

}

int UDPStreamSender::SendSegment(const Segment* seg)
{
    char* sMsg = new char[segLength];
    sMsg[0] = NULL;

    memcpy(sMsg, (char*)&seg->seqNum, SEQ_NUM_LEN);
    memcpy(sMsg + SEQ_NUM_LEN, seg->data, msgSegLen);

    int st = streamSender->Send(sMsg, segLength);

    delete sMsg;
    return st;
}

void UDPStreamSender::SendBuffer()
{

    bufLock.lock();
    bool hasElms = sendBuffer->hasElems();
    bufLock.unlock();

    while (_isRunning || hasElms)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mtx_lock(bufLock);
        size_t firstUnsent = sendBuffer->firstUnsent();
        size_t buffCount = sendBuffer->count();

        while (!sendBuffer->hasElems())
        {
            stopIfEmpty.wait_for(mtx_lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
            if (_allRecived)
                return;
        }

        for (size_t i = firstUnsent; i < buffCount; i++)
        {

            Segment sSeg = sendBuffer->at(i);
            int st = SendSegment(&sSeg);
            if (st >= segLength)
            {
                sSeg.isSent = true;
                DWORD j = GetTickCount();
                sSeg.timeOutTick = j + timeOutTicks;
                sendBuffer->Replace(i, &sSeg);
                sendBuffer->sendSeg();
                cout << "SEG sent: SeqNum=" << sSeg.seqNum << endl;
            }

        }

        hasElms = sendBuffer->hasElems();

        mtx_lock.unlock();
    }
}

void UDPStreamSender::AckRecive()
{
    char* ackMessage;
    while (!_allRecived)
    {

        ackMessage = ackReciver->Recive();

        string ackMsg(ackMessage);
        if (ackMsg.substr(0, 3).compare("ACK") != 0)
            continue;

        unsigned short ackSeqNum = 0;
        memcpy(&ackSeqNum, ackMessage + 3, 2);

        cout << "ACK recieved: seqNum=" << ackSeqNum << endl;

        std::unique_lock<mutex> mtx_lock(bufLock);
        sendBuffer->Ack(ackSeqNum);
        _allRecived = !sendBuffer->hasElems() || !_isRunning;
        mtx_lock.unlock();
        stopifFull.notify_one();

    }
}

void UDPStreamSender::ManageTimeout()
{
    bufLock.lock();
    bool hasElms = sendBuffer->hasElems();
    bufLock.unlock();

    while (!_allRecived)
    {

        std::unique_lock<mutex> mtx_lock(bufLock);
        while (!sendBuffer->hasElems())
        {
            stopIfEmpty.wait_for(mtx_lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
            if (_allRecived)
                return;
        }

        DWORD segTick = sendBuffer->first().timeOutTick;
        DWORD cTick = GetTickCount();
        if (sendBuffer->hasElems() && cTick > segTick)
        { // timeout, resend all buffer
            sendBuffer->resendAll();
            cout << "Timeout: seqNum=" << sendBuffer->first().seqNum << endl;
        }

        hasElms = sendBuffer->hasElems();

        mtx_lock.unlock();
    }
}
```