# What's the most efficient way to async send data while async receiving with 0MQ?

Tags: c++, zeromq

I've got a ROUTER/DEALER setup where both ends need to be able to receive and send data asynchronously, as soon as it's available. The model is pretty much  0MQ's async C++ server: http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:asyncsrv

Both the client and the server workers poll, when there's data available they call a callback. While this happens, from another thread (!) I'm putting data in a `std::deque`. In each poll-forever thread, I check the `deque` (under lock), and if there are items there, I send them out to the specified DEALER id (the id is placed in the queue).

But I can't help thinking that this is not idiomatic 0MQ. The mutex is possibly a design problem. Plus, memory consumption can probably get quite high if enough time passes between polls (and data accumulates in the `deque`).

The only alternative I can think of is having another DEALER thread connect to an `inproc` each time I want to send out data, and just have it send it and exit. However, this implies a connect per item of data sent + construction and destruction of a socket, and it's probably not ideal.

Is there an idiomatic 0MQ way to do this, and if so, what is it?

Comment: What are your target latencies [us] and data payload-sizes [B] + peak-throughput  cadence [Hz] given nCPU-cores [1] and such process-allocatable RAM [GB]?

Comment: I don't yet have precise requirements, I'm merely interested if my current design looks clean or not in relation to the 0MQ design philosophy (which appears to completely discourage locking, if I'm reading it correctly).

Answer (score 0):

I dont fully understand your design but I do understand your concern about using locks.

In most cases you can redesign your code to remove the use of locks using zeromq PAIR sockets and inproc.

Do you really need a std::deque? If not you could just use a zerom queue as its just a queue that you can read/write from from different threads using sockets.

If you really need the deque then encapsulate it into its own thread (a class would be nice) and make its API (push etc) accessible via inproc sockets.

So like I said before I may be on the wrong track but in 99% of cases I have come across you can always remove the locks completely with some ZMQ_PAIR/inproc if you need signalling.

Answer (score -1):

0mq queue has limited buffer size and it can be controlled. So memory issue will get to some point and then dropping data will occur. For that reason you may consider using conflate option leaving only most recent data in queue.

In a case of single server and communication within single machine with many threads I suggest using publish/subscribe model where with conflate option you will receive new data as soon as you read buffer and won't have to worry about memory. And it removes blocking queue problem.

As for your implementation you are quite right, it is not best design but it is quite unavoidable. I suggest checking question [Access std::deque from 3 threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122646/access-stddeque-from-3-threads?rq=1) while it answers your problem, it may not be the best approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not what I'm asking. I do know how to safely access the `deque` from multiple threads, and switching to PUB/SUB will not solve the problem I'm asking about.

Comment: Is it 0MQ problem then?

Comment: I'm really only asking if, _given_ the ROUTER/DEALER setup, is it better to do as I'm doing or I should have another thread `connect()` (and create / destroy a socket) for each send. Or if there's some other way (again, with ROUTER/DEALER).